# Best practice to call module's function based on argument

Tags: rust

What's the best way to call a module's function based on the input argument?

```rust
mod programs;

fn run(day: i32) {
    match day {
        1 => programs::day_01::main(),
        2 => programs::day_02::main(),
        _ => println!(""),
    }
}

fn main() {
    run(1);
}
```

Comment: Way too vague and open-ended. Sure using match is fine.

Comment: Shortest? Most performant? What is "best"?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I meant best practice

Comment: Best practice is only vaguely defined, but using `match` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A macro can be used to generate a match statement with all names and corresponding functions.

```rust
macro_rules! dispatch_to {
    ($val:expr => {$($func:ident),*}) => {
            match $val {
                $(
                    stringify!($func) => $func(),
                )*
                _ => {},
            }
    }
}
```

But you still need to provide the list of available functions in `dispatch()`:

```rust
fn dispatch(s: &str) {
    // this is how you can use the macro
    dispatch_to!(s => {func_1, func_2});
}

fn main() {
    let s: String = "func_2".into();
    
    dispatch(&s);
}


fn func_1(){
    println!("Function 1");
}

fn func_2() {
    println!("Function 2");
}
```

Another way may be to locate the symbol in the binary using `dlopen` and `dlsym`.